# How to get data from nested JSON decoded array and save it in the database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to save the response received from api . Please check below files. I am getting error while saving it in the database using eloquent.

Here my dd($responseData) result while making request to api

```
array:2 [▼ // app\Jobs\ProcessRemainingItems.php:49
  "success" => 1
  "results" => array:1 [▶
    0 => array:4 [▶
      "FI" => "138706251"
      "event_id" => "6728030"
      "main" => array:3 [▶
        "updated_at" => "1685861441"
        "key" => "#AC#B3#C20891381#D8#E17086800#F8#"
        "sp" => array:1 [▶
          "to_win_the_match" => array:3 [▶
            "id" => "1246"
            "name" => "To Win the Match"
            "odds" => array:2 [▶
              0 => array:3 [▶
                "id" => "737295672"
                "odds" => "3.00"
                "name" => "1"
              ]
              1 => array:3 [▶
                "id" => "737295679"
                "odds" => "1.40"
                "name" => "2"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      "schedule" => array:3 [▶
        "updated_at" => "1685860125"
        "key" => "#AC#B3#C20891381#D720#E1246#F720#"
        "sp" => array:1 [▶
          "main" => array:2 [▶
            0 => array:3 [▶
              "id" => "737295672"
              "odds" => "3.00"
              "name" => "1"
            ]
            1 => array:3 [▶
              "id" => "737295679"
              "odds" => "1.40"
              "name" => "2"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Below is Migration File

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('upcoming_cricket_events_odds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('FI');
            $table->string('event_id')->nullable();
            $table->json('innings_1')->nullable();
            $table->json('main')->nullable();
            $table->json('match')->nullable();
            $table->json('others')->nullable();
            $table->json('player')->nullable();
            $table->json('schedule')->nullable();
            $table->json('team')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('upcoming_cricket_events_odds');
    }
};
```

Below is Model File

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\BetsApi;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UpcomingCricketEventsOdds extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'FI',
        'event_id',
        'innings_1',
        'main',
        'match',
        'others',
        'player',
        'schedule',
        'team',

    ];


    protected $casts = [

        'innings_1' => 'json',
        'main' => 'json',
        'match' => 'json',
        'others' => 'json',
        'player' => 'json',
        'schedule' => 'json',
        'team' => 'json',
    ];
    // Define the inverse relationship with UpcomingCricketEvent
    public function event(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UpcomingCricketEvents::class);
    }
}
```

Below is my Job File which i plan to run every 5 minutes

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\BetsApi\UpcomingCricketEvents;
use App\Models\BetsApi\UpcomingCricketEventsOdds;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class ProcessRemainingItems implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $chunkSize = 10; // Number of records to fetch per chunk
        $processedCount = 0; // Counter for processed items

        do {
            $items = UpcomingCricketEvents::skip($processedCount)->take($chunkSize)->get();

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $eventId = $item->api_event_id;

                // Make an API request to fetch odds for the event
                $response = Http::get('https://api.b365api.com/v3/bet365/prematch', [
                    'FI' => $eventId,
                    'token' => config('services.BetsApi.token'),
                ]);

                $responseData = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
                dd($responseData);
                $odds = new UpcomingCricketEventsOdds();

                $odds->FI = $responseData['results'][0]['FI'];
                $odds->event_id = $responseData['results'][0]['event_id'];
                $odds->innings_1 = json_encode($responseData['results'][0]['innings_1']);
                $odds->main = json_encode($responseData['results'][0]['main']);
                $odds->match = json_encode($responseData['results'][0]['match']);
                $odds->others = json_encode($responseData['results'][0]['others']);
                $odds->player = json_encode($responseData['results'][0]['player']);
                $odds->schedule = json_encode($responseData['results'][0]['schedule']);
                $odds->team = json_encode($responseData['results'][0]['team']);

// Save the odds record
                $odds->save();



                $processedCount += count($items);
            }
        } while ($items->isNotEmpty());
    }
}
```

I want to save the response in the database but it does not save and gives error

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'FI' doesn't have a default value